# Does $\sum^\infty_1(-1)^n(\frac {1+(-1)^n}{n})$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does $\sum^\infty_1(-1)^n\left(\frac {1+(-1)^n}{n}\right)$ converge or diverge?

**My Work:** At first I noticed that it looks like an alternating series and wanted to say it converges because $\frac {1+(-1)^n}{n}$ goes to zero, but I noticed that for $n=1$, we have $0$, for $n=2$ we have $\frac {2}{n}$, for $n=3$, $0$. So it's not really decreasing. 
From here I only could do this by intuition that this behaves like $\frac {1}{n}$ or maybe less than it since we have $0$ every second element. so it diverges. 
Would really like to know if what I did is right and if the series converges or diverges. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: **HINT** $1+(-1)^{2k+1}=0$ for all $k$. Only even numbers matter

Comment: Note, $(-1)^n(1+(-1)^n)=(-1)^n+1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. This series is simply$$0+\frac22+0+\frac24+0+\frac26+\cdots$$which converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac2{2n}$ converges. But this is the harmonic series. Therefore, the series diverges.

Comment: You mean $2/2n$, no?

Comment: I sure do! I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n=(-1)^n(\frac {1+(-1)^n}{n})$ und $S_n= a_1+a_2+...+a_n.$ Show that $a_{2n-1}=0$ and $a_{2n}=1/n.$

Furthermore show that $S_{2n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}.$

Hence $(S_n)$ is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see it,
$$
\sum^N_1(-1)^n\left(\frac {1+(-1)^n}{n}\right)=
\sum^N_1\left(\frac {(-1)^n}{n}\right)+
\sum^N_1\left(\frac {1}{n}\right)
$$
Now as $N \to \infty$, note $\sum^N_1\left(\frac {(-1)^n}{n}\right)$ converges and $\sum^N_1\left(\frac {1}{n}\right)$ diverges.  Therefore $\sum^N_1(-1)^n\left(\frac {1+(-1)^n}{n}\right)$ diverges.

---

More generally, in
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N (a_n + b_n) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n+\sum_{n=1}^N b_n,
$$
if any two of the three series converge, then so does the third and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n + b_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n .
$$